# share data Service with duplicated component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I have a duplicted component which is using a shared service and using subject behavior.

Here's my component

```
export class HelloComponent  {
   message:string;
   printedMessage:string

  constructor(private data: DataService, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.data.messageSource.value;
  }

  updateService(){
    this.data.changeMessage(this.message);
    this.printedMessage=this.data.messageSource.value
    //this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  navigateToSibling(){
    this.router.navigate(['/sibling']);
  }
}
```

**data service**

```
export class DataService {

  messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

**parent Component**

```
<hello></hello>
<hello></hello>
```

Here's a [stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-example-vrc5jk)

I would that when I make a change on the component 1 the duplicated component get also this change. ( when I click save , I trigger the `save()` function on both of the components , [see here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-example-vrc5jk) )

Actually when I change the input in the first component, It get printed only in this component not in the duplicated.

are the component using difference instance of shared data.service ? if yes , how to make them using the same ?

Comment: You can add, directly in the template: `{{data?.messageSource | async}}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to your data service's observable inside the consuming HelloComponent.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.data.messageSource.value;
    this.data.messageSource.subscribe(message => this.printedMessage = message); // Subscribing to changes here
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working , what I'm looking for is to run the function `updateService()` on the second component when I click the first

Comment: @HamzaHaddad Well, you are doing it wrong then... You really should leverage the observables. assign the `BehaviorSubject` to message and use `{{message | async}}`. And for other values use similar approach.